# What are important rules of static analysis to use in our automated scripts?

Tags: automated-testing, sonarqube, static-analysis, static-testing, best-practices

I am fan of improving the quality not only of the product I test but also for the test itself.

I want to create other customized rules for integrating with sonarqube that does not exist in classic tools.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you elaborate on what you are using in sonarqube.. I enabled coding rules, test coverage, code duplication, complexity, and architecture

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking - can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I m searching for rules that we can use with static analysis tools like complexity, Duplicate code detection, metrics about quality .... 
I want to add customized rules to test my automated script code (static testing)

Answer (score 1):

Try out

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code

Other possible ways

1. If coding guidelines and standard followed.
2. Duplicate code.
3. Coding guidelines followed.
4. Design principle effectiveness .

Answer (score 1):

How about an code review from an experienced senior developer, so that you can focus more on practical tips.

Experience is incomparable to any tool at least in the current state of the tools.

Having said that, currently for JavaScript , we use linter tools for static code analysis which comes as plugins/extensions in all major IDEs.

Comment: You are right experience is necessary ; but why not jumping this experience into a tool

Comment: Ok , currently for JavaScript , we use linter tools for static code analysis which comes as plugins in all major IDEs.